# Window resize script has an unexpected side effect

Tags: javascript, resize, window-resize

I wrote a short javascript to resize a popup window when an element is added to the page.
For some reason each time a new element is added the width of the window decreases by 4 pixels, even though it should stay the same because the width of added elements is always the same.

Any idea what could be causing this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resizeWin(){
            var winHeight=document.getElementById('bodyArea').offsetHeight;
            var winWidth=document.getElementById('bodyArea').offsetWidth;
            alert(winWidth);
            window.resizeTo(winWidth+20,winHeight+80);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="javascript:resizeWin()"> 
<div id="bodyArea" style="overflow: hidden;"> 
    <form id="courseDetails" action="/CourseRegistration/Courses" method="POST" width: 300px">
        <table>
                //blah blah, constant size
        </table>

        <input type="button" value="Add Session" onclick="addRow('addCourse');resizeWin();" />
        <input type="button" value="RemoveSession" onclick="deleteRow('addCourse');resizeWin();" />

        <table id="addCourse" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="day">
                        <option value="1">Sunday</option>
                        <option value="2">Monday</option>
                        <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="5">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="6">Friday</option>
                        <option value="7">Saturday</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="start">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                       <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="duration">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="addCourse" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser is it happening in?

Comment: You are not considering padding, would be my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the

`<form id="courseDetails" action="/CourseRegistration/Courses" method="POST" width: 300px">`

You're missing the openning ="  of the width; try `width="300px"` maybe thats making some bug.

Comment: In HTML width and height are defined without units. So, the right variant is `width="300"`

Comment: You can use 'px' or 'em' units, for example: 300px = 18.75em, so it would be almost the same if you use: 
`width="300px"`
of
`width="18.75em"`

Comment: Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.6  In pure HTML it is possible to use only numbers (mean pixels) and percentage values. Numbers with `px, pt, em, ex, in, mm, cm` are used in CSS.

Comment: And also 1em is equal to the size of current element's font. E.g. if you set the font for `<DIV>` as 20px, 2em = 40px.

Comment: Exactly, it depends on the size of browser default size, it's not always the same, here's a good [converter](http://pxtoem.com/) for that and it has a good documentation. Lets see if any of this helped @Dude with his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to ensure that `body` fit window:

```
BODY{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```